# Fill height css flexbox with many nested containers

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using AdminLTE, and in 1 particular page, I need the body of the card to stretch the whole available height.

There are a bunch of nested containers which I cannot delete.
HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 937px;">
    <div class="content-header">
        header 1
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        header 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="mycontent">
                            content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I think that the height on `#content-wrapper` is set by javascript.

Normally, `#content-wrapper` and `.content` are `display: block` and do not stretch to the full height.

.row is normally a `display: flex`

I need all of these containers to stretch, so that `#mycontent` can use all the available space.
I tried with this CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row,
.card {
    display: block;
}
.content-header,
.card-header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.content,
.card-body,
.col-md-12,
.card,
.row {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-items: stretch
}


#mycontent {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Elements which do stretch to the available height:

- div .content-wrapper
- section .content

Not stretching:

- div .row and its children

Does the problem lie with the `<section>` tag?

How can I best achieve my goal?

**UPDATE: Working solution:**

```
.content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 250px); /* offset for the sidebar */
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; /* as parent FBL */
    flex: 1;                               /* as child FBL  */
}
.content-header,
.card-header {
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
    flex: 0
}
.content,
.row,
.col-md-12,
.card,
.card-body,
#mycontent {
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; /* as parent FBL */
    flex: 1;                               /* as child FBL  */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes 'getting used to', but it is often convenient to simply turn all elements for a 'cardlist' into *flexbox containers (FBL)*.

steps to follow:

- make `html` and `body` fill the full viewport
- make the cardlist and cards flexbox column containers
- have the FBL elements all stretch to fill their parents
- define exceptions to the the above
- define eye-candy

Result is the following **snippet**

```css
/********************************/
/* some convenient global rules */
/********************************/
*, ::before, ::after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box }

/* fill full viewport */
html, body  { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }

/* remove default body spacing */
body { margin: 0 }

/*******************/
/* Demo SO72942064 */
/*******************/
.content-wrapper {
    min-height: auto !important; /* to override JS, [OPTIONAL] */
    height: 100%;                /* fill parent */
}
/*
    'content-wrapper' and all decendants are
    flexbox containers (FBL) stretching to fill their parent.
*/
.content-wrapper, .content-wrapper * {
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; /* as parent FBL */
    flex: 1;                               /* as child FBL  */
    width: 100%;
}

/* headers have exceptions to above rule [OPTIONAL] */
[class$="header" i] { flex-flow: row wrap; flex: 0 }
/* ...classnames ending with "header", case-insensitive... */

/******************/
/* eye-candy only */
/******************/
.content-wrapper * { background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%,.05) }
.card-body         { background-color: hsl(0,100%,50%,.05) }

[class$="header" i], .card-body { padding: 0.5rem }

* { outline: 1px dashed } /* for debugging */
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 937px;">
    <div class="content-header">
        header 1
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        header 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="mycontent">
                            content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! the rules were a bit too generic and interfered with my content. I made the code uglier but got it to work as intended. Thanks

Comment: I have a follow up question.. now that #mycontent is a flex item of the correct height, is it possible to keep it that height and prevent its children from stretching it further? (I want to hide any overflow)

Comment: @Valentino I'm glad you understand that my demo is just a 'base' to build on. Follow up: you can always opt to `#mycontent, #mycontent * { display: block }`, overriding the FBL settings, which also disables the FBL specific stretching/sizing, but that may turn out confusing. I alway give my cards a *minimum* fit of 320x480 or 360x640 (very small and small mobile-ish). A nice trick is e.g. `.card { width: min(18rem,100%); height: min(43rem, 100%) }`. It will either be at least 18x38rem (with 1rem spacing on either side, as 20rem = 320px, 40rem= 640px), or fill the viewport when smaller.

Comment: @Valentino also try working with `aspect-ratio`. For scrolling `#mycontent`, simply make it `overflow: auto`. I just noticed: with a grid of cards, your content wrapper should probably read `.content-wrapper { flex-flow: row wrap }`...

Comment: @Valentino you might find this [Codepen: Flexbox N-grid](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/gOvWZwq) interesting. It's essentially a simple base for all kinds of *Flexbox* grids without '@Media' or use of JS. Check the CSS *mechanism* section.

Comment: thank you Rene, but I do not have a grid on this page. Only 1 card. As it is now, it's good enough. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the problem is this one:

> **If a child elements wants to set its `height` attribute to a pourcentage** (typically 100% in this case) **then the parent element has to have a `height` set as well. Setting the `min-height` on the parent will unfortunately not work**.

Here I set the `html` and `body` elements to a height of 100%. I did the same for the boxes that needed to grow in your structure. To avoid them beeing to big I used the border-box model for the box sizing.

You may need to find where to do it in your case as I expect your HTML is just a portion of the page. You might need to override the inline styling with the use of `!important`. Typically to override `style="min-height: 937px;"` you can do `.content-wrapper { min-height: 400px !important; }`

```css
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  /* You have to set a height to the parents so that you can set
     a height to the children. Setting a min-height will not let
     you set a height: 100% on the child. Yes, this is anoying. */
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  /* We can't use margins on the body because of the box model
     using borders and which can't include the margins. So we
     replace this body marging by a html padding. */
  padding: 1em;
}

/* Both the .content-wrapper and the card use flexbox vertically. */
.content-wrapper,
.content-wrapper .card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* The .content-wrapper and some containers inside
   section.content should grow to 100%. */
.content-wrapper,
.content-wrapper .row,
.content-wrapper .col-md-12,
.content-wrapper .card,
.content-wrapper .card-body > div {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The second cells have to grow but not the headers. */
.content-wrapper .content,
.content-wrapper .card-body {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-wrapper > * {
  padding: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-10deg, #d299c2 0%, #fef9d7 100%);
}

/* Just color all divs inside the card to see them grow. */
.card * {
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 200px;">
    <div class="content-header">
        header 1
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        header 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="mycontent">
                            content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the codepen I created to try to find a solution: https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/VwXKvvv?editors=1100

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. I marked the other answer as the solving one, as it provided a more complete set of css attributes to work with

Answer (score -1):

I think best to use `<table>` in this case, уоu won't need additional CSS to make it stretch.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 py-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body p-0 m-0">
                    <div class="container-fluid m-0 h-100">
                        <div class="row h-100">
                            <table class="card-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="px-3 pt-3">
                                            <p>Header</p>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="px-3 align-top">
                                            <p>Content</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="px-3">
                                            <p>Footer</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoted, sinde OP clearly states _There are a bunch of nested containers which I cannot delete_

Comment: @Gerard So repeat the same technique for the nested containers.